# Laravel FormRequest Validation Rule

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-validation, laravel-formrequest

In my Laravel Application when someone edits their Profile and waits till admin approval, they cannot edit the profile again.I need to implement this rule in FormRequest while user profile is edited.

My `User` model `hasMany` profile, but I am taking only the active profile,

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Profile::class)->where('active', 1);
}
```

So when user edits profile I will insert into Profile table as `active = 0`, and update the flag in my User table "`profile_review_pending = 1`"

Now what I need is I need to define some rule in FormRequest like if `profile_review_pending =1` then don't allow editing. Can this be done using exists or something like that?

Comment: Are you wanting an error to be returned or are you just wanting to prevent the user from updating their profile? Please could you also share your route definition and the code you have in your `FormRequest` so far.

Comment: try `required_if:anotherfield,value,...`
The field under validation must be present and not empty if the anotherfield field is equal to any value.

Comment: @Rwd I want to prevent user from updating, its just a resource route. Also I havnt written anything in FormRequest. Now what I think is instead of handling this is in Rule, what I can do to prevent user from going to edit form.

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to suggest. As a quick solution you could use the `authorize()` method in the `FormRequest` to prevent the profile from being updated. A more robust way, that you can then use throughout your application, would be to  make a policy (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#creating-policies).

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a custom validation rule, 
implement the `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule` interface or use a Closure. The custom rule is then used directly in a validator.

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class ReviewPendingValidationRule implements Rule
{
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return $value == 1;
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return ':Review is pending';
    }
}
```

In your controller

```
public function store()
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'profile_review_pending' => [new ReviewPendingValidationRule]
    ]);
}
```